# How to display "help" command in linux terminal using C?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I need a little help on simulating a terminal command within a C program. More specifically the "help" command.

Just to clarify what's going on here. I'm working on an assignment to build a C program under the Linux environment that will prompt the user to enter a command (user will type an actual Linux command within the C program), the program will read the user input, and output the result of the command as if you were typing the command in the terminal.

I'm new to working in both Linux and C, but I think I can build the main program. I just want to learn how to run Linux commands within a C program. I researched and have successfully done so with a few commands, such as "clear" and "ls", but I have not been able to get "help" or even "exit" to work.

Here's how I got "ls" to work:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       system("ls");

       return 0;
    }
```

I complied and ran that program and it did exactly what's expected, run the command as if I was typing in the terminal. Now I tried the same thing for "help", but it didn't work in saying the command was "not found." So I searched it up and found that the shell looks in particular directories to execute certain stuff. "Ls" in particular was in /usr/bin. The problem is, I can't seem to find the directory where "help" is stored. Am I in the right direction in looking for a particular directory or is it not possible to run "help" within a C program?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `help` and `exit` are not Linux commands! These are bash-builtins.

Comment: Are you using bash or is there another default shell? I just tried it and it worked fine. I would test with 
    system("bash -c help");
to see if that worked.

Comment: Yes, I'm using bash. I'll try that and see if it works for me.

Comment: @crazy_pants Okay, So I tried as you mentioned and it worked perfectly! I have a concern though. The others are mentioning that "help" is a bash builtin and the system's shell interpreter looks in /bin/sh to run commands. So how exactly does "system("bash -c help")" work? Does it change directories or something of the sort?

Comment: Look at `system(3)` documentation.  `system()` uses `sh(1)` and not `bash(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
system("bash -c help");
```

instead of just "help". It seems that your default shell isn't bash but something else. "bash -c" simply specifies a command specifically to bash (-c option means "command"). You can check this via command line by looking at where /bin/sh is pointing.

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

should give something to the tune of

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep  9 19:30 /bin/sh -> bash*
```

or something else

Comment: thank you very much! system("bash -c help") works great! I literally spent more than a few hours trying to figure this thing out. Regarding the shell, I really don't know what I'm running. I want to say bash, but I honestly have no clue. I tried ls -l /bin/sh and it returned lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 16 17:53 /bin/sh -> dash. If I run echo $0, it returns bash so I'm not sure what's going on. Thanks again though!

Comment: It has nothing to do with your shell.  As `system(3)` doc says, it uses `sh(1)` and not your default shell.

Answer (score 4):

`help` is a bash builtin, not a real program you can run.

`system(3)` uses your system's shell interpreter (`/bin/sh`) to run commands, which happens to have no `help` builtin on your system.

Answer (score 0):

As `system(3)` doc says, it uses `/bin/sh` for executing your command line.  `/bin/sh` is not the same as `/bin/bash` anyway.  Even if you have only `bash(1)` in your system, when you run it as `sh`, it behaves as if you where using plain `sh` (runs in compatibility mode), so no `help` command available.